# create a pipeline in callback funtion gstreamer

Tags: callback, gstreamer, pipeline

Hi

I want to know if it is correct create a pipeline within a callback
I give you an example of what I have implemented:

I have a callback that is responsible for receiving error messages. When I get an error that's the problem I launch a new pipeline to the problem fixed. This works but not if it is correct implementation or can give any problems later

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is completely correct to do so, we do that in pitivi for example : https://git.gnome.org/browse/pitivi/tree/pitivi/timeline/previewers.py#n965

Ideally, it is best to make sure no errors happen though :)